# Undefined with class implementing abstract class

Tags: typescript

I'm not an expert in Javascript, and I'm conscious that my issue with the follow Typescript code starts there. But I'm stuck here in last 36 hours, in Typescript I'm having an undefined issues and I will let the code explain the rest:

```
window.onload = () => { var i = new IPropIndex(new IPropService()); };

interface IIDocService<T> {
    getSingle(): IPropDoc;
}

class IPropService implements IIDocService<T> {
    getSingle(): IPropDoc { return new IPropDoc(); }
}

abstract class IDocIndex<T> {
    constructor(public _IDocType: string, public _IIDocService: IIDocService<T>) {
        console.log(this._IDocType); //NOT UNDEFINED
        this.methodB();
    }

    public abstract methodA();

    public methodB() {
        this.methodA(this.methodC); //**UNDEFINED**
    }

    public methodC() {
        console.log(this._IDocType);
    }
}

class IPropIndex extends IDocIndex<IPropDoc> {
    constructor(public _IPropService: IPropService) {
        super('iPROP', _IPropService);
        console.log(this._IPropService); //NOT UNDEFINED
    }

    public methodA(callback: any): void {
        console.log(this._IPropService); //**UNDEFINED**
        callback();
    }
}

class IPropDoc { public name: string; }
```

How can I have this solution without having undefined issues signed in code!?
Thanks.

Comment: how are you executing `methodA` and `methodB`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> console.log(this._IPropService); //**UNDEFINED**

You clearly have the wrong `this`.

## Fix

Use an arrow

```
public methodA = (callback: any) => {
    console.log(this._IPropService); //**UNDEFINED**
    callback();
}
```

More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html